# flink / spark stream - track user inactivity

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to Flink and have a use case I do not know how to approach.

I have events coming

```
{
"id" : "AAA",
"event" : "someEvent",
"eventTime" : "2019/09/14 14:04:25:235"
}
```

**I want to create a table (in elastic / oracle) that tracks user inactivity.**

id || lastEvent || lastEventTime || inactivityTime

My final goal is to alert if some group of users are in active more then X minutes.

This table should be updated every 1 minute.

**I do not have prior knowledge of all my id's. new ids can come at any time..**

I thought maybe just use simple process function to emit event if present or else emit timestamp (that will update the inactivity column).

**Questions**

1. Regarding my solution - I still need to have another piece of code that check if event is null or not and update accordingly. If null --> update inactivity. else update lastEvent.
   Can / should this code by in the same flink/spark job?
2. How do I deal with new ids?
3. Also, how can this use case can be dealt in spark structured stream?

   ```
   input
       .keyBy("id")
       .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
       .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction());

   public class MyProcessWindowFunction
           extends ProcessWindowFunction<Tuple2<String, Long>, Tuple2<Long, Object>> {

       @Override
       public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<Tuple2<String, Long>> input, Collector<Tuple2<Long, Object>> out) {
           Object obj = null;
           while(input.iterator().hasNext()){
               obj = input.iterator().next();
           }

           if (obj!=null){
               out.collect(Tuple2.of(context.timestamp(), obj));
           } else {
               out.collect(Tuple2.of(context.timestamp(), null));
           }

       }
   ```

Comment: As for _"Also, how can this use case can be dealt in spark structured stream?"_ I'd ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `KeyedProcessFunction` instead of the Windowing API for these requirements. [1] The stream is keyed by id.

`KeyedProcessFunction#process` is invoked for each record of the stream, you can keep state and schedule timers. You could schedule a timer every minute, and for each od store the last event seen in state. When the timer fires, you either emit the event and clear the state.

Personally, I would only store the last event seen in the database and calculate the inactivity time when querying the database. This way you can clear state after each emission and the possibly unbounded key space does not result in every growing managed state in Flink.

Hope this helps.

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/process_function.html

Comment: With respect to Spark Streaming: I am by no means a Structured Streaming expert, but to my knowledge use cases, where you want to take action based on individual events (update state, timers, emission) are inherently difficult to implement and/or inefficient in Spark Structured Streaming.

Comment: Calculating inactivity only when querying is smart but not for my use case. Because I want alert when someone is inactive longer than X minutes.
Also, can you please give the smallest possible example of your idea with triggers and state.